# Сортировка по области (point)

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица в которой есть столбец `point` с координатами точки

У меня есть координаты и размеры прямоугольника (x, y, w, h), как сделать запрос, чтобы все `point` которые входят в этот прямоугольник отсортировались и вывелись вверх?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте функцию [MBRContains](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-mysql-specific.html#function_mbrcontains) либо [MBRWithin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-mysql-specific.html#function_mbrwithin) - в описанном случае они дадут одинаковый результат.

Comment: На сколько я понял, оно выводит объекты лежащие в области, но мне надо вывести ВСЕ объекты, а те, которые в области отсортировать и вывести в топ запроса

Comment: Мне нужно что-то типо `order by MBRContains`

Comment: Вполне валидная конструкция

Comment: А можно сделать запрос с сортировкой без указания области? Просто чтобы самые ближние точки к `point` выводились вверх, а самые дальние наоборот вниз запроса?

Comment: Наверное, это уже другой вопрос, создам новый тред

Comment: Тогда просто считайте расстояние (вернее, квадрат расстояния) и сортируйте по нему.